# Easiest way to view Lotus Notes databases in Ubuntu Studio 17.10?

Tags: email-client

What is the easiest way to view my Lotus Notes databases in Ubuntu - is it to install Lotus Notes (and if so how would I do that - I'm running 32 bit Ubuntu Studio 17.10), or is there any tool that can 'extract' my Notes emails into an Ubuntu email client ?